# Linux: Compare large files

Tags: linux, database, perl, large-files

I am downloading the .COM zone file every day. It's a list of all .COM domains in the world with their primary nameserver.

Sample of the zone file:

```
DAYTONOHIOJOBS NS NS1.HOSTINGNET
DAYTONOHIOJOBS NS NS2.HOSTINGNET
DAYTONOHIOMAP NS NS1.HOSTINGNET
DAYTONOHIOMAP NS NS2.HOSTINGNET
DAYTONOHIONEWS NS NS1.HOSTINGNET
DAYTONOHIONEWS NS NS2.HOSTINGNET
```

To save in disk space, you can see .COM has been removed from the domain name (it's all .COM anyway).
The same goes for the nameserver (if it ends in .COM it has been removed).

This zone file is around 270,000,000 lines and about 9 GB.

My goal is to monitor a specific nameserver. Every day I want a list of all domains with that specific nameserver, but also a list of all new domains with that nameserver (new as in: yesterday this domain didn't have that nameserver yet).

I wrote a perl script to open and load "yesterdays" database and then open "todays" database and loop and compare. But this takes hours and lots of memory.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you make assumptions about sortedness of the zone file?

Comment: A tangential question on the compression scheme: especially with the virtually-unrestricted-TLDs world we have now, how do you differentiate a nameserver named ns3.foobar.com with the .com removed from one named simply ns3.foobar?

Comment: It's not always sorted in the same way.
Regarding comparing ns3.foobar.com with ns3.foobar.* - it is sort of irrelevant (for me), because the nameserver I am monitoring only has a .com extension, and if it has anything else it is not the one I need.

Comment: The natural way to solve it would be to save the relevant portions of the big file to smaller files, e.g. `20141031_NS1.HOSTINGNET`. Then do comparison of the smaller files. It would be easier to suggest ways to speed up your process if we could see the code you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, judging by what I know:

Have the script read the first file. For each line that corresponds to the nameserver of interest, add the entry to a hashmap.

Have the script read the second file. For each line that corresponds to the nameserver of interest, check if the entry is in the hashmap. If it isn't, it is new. If it is, it is unchanged - remove it from the hashmap.

At the end, all entries still left in the hashmap have been removed.

This does assume that the hashmap with this particular nameservers domains fits into memory, but on a reasonable machine and for a reasonable nameserver, this seems a reasonable assumption...

Comment: This is what I have been doing. Adding the old file in a hashmap and then looping over the new file. The problem is I am monitoring the biggest nameserver in the world which has millions of domain names and I am simply running out of memory after a while (unless I add 40gb of RAM but that is expensive).

Comment: If memory is the main concern, several options are open to you: 1) do several runs, each time only processing domains starting with a certain letter (or otherwise partitioning the data), 2) use a database, 3) build a binary tree so that effectively 'a.aaalonglonglonglong' and 'b.bbblonglonglonglong' would result in 'longlonglonglong' only taking up memory once (though this would require clever decision making to avoid pointers taking up more space than is saved). If 'mistakes' are permissible, you could also just compare checksums.

Answer (score 1):

You may `grep` today and yestarday files for lines with the nameserver and compare the two results. (`grep` - command line unix tool)

You may keep compressed files (gzip) and use `zgrep` for initial grep.